# Tate module whose maximal semisimple subrepresentation is a line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

An abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is cool if the maximal semisimple subrepresentation of its Tate module is a line.

Are there cool abelian varieties of arbitrarily high dimension? What about the ones with good reduction?